# Trouble with rotating data in accordance with a "spline" polynomial?

Tags: r, rotation, spline, polynomials, derivative

Here is the code that the issue is in:

```
angles = -atan(deriv)

angles = angles*(180/pi)



#shift coordinates onto their polynomials

d[1:mtp,3] = d[1:mtp,3] + poly[,2]



#rotated storage matrix

rrr = as.data.frame(matrix(data = NA, ncol = 2, nrow = 9000))



#for each moment, take in old coordinates and export newly rotated

for(i in 1:mtp){

rotm = matrix(data = c(c(cos(angles[i]),sin(angles[i])),

c(-sin(angles[i]),cos(angles[i]))), ncol=2, nrow = 2)

rotate.1 = d[i,2:3] - poly[i,]

rotate.2 = rotm %*% t(rotate.1)

rotate.3 = rotate.2 + poly[i,]

rrr[i,] = rotate.3

}



#overwrite coordinates with rotations

d[1:mtp,2:3] = rrr
```

"deriv" is a numeric vector containing the derivative at each point along the polynomial spline "poly" with columns 1:2 the x and y. "angles" therefore contains the calculated angle to rotate by at each point. "d" is the initial data matrix, with columns 2:3 the x and y.

[Data to be translated and rotated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iudX8.png)

["Spline" polynomial along which data will be translated and rotated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmpCI.png)

[Angles along polynomial used during rotation (derived from derivative)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWYke.png)

[Data + Spline (translated)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbZAB.png)

[Translated and (incorrectly) rotated data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ytiO.png)

Comment: Could you `dput()` the data or pseudodata?

Comment: sure thing: 
[Translated Data](https://www.mediafire.com/file/ga6r2rg4j374gve/translateddata.txt/file)
[Rotated Data](https://www.mediafire.com/file/kz7s1ts9yryfhdd/rotateddata.txt/file)
[Rotation Angles](https://www.mediafire.com/file/5mv7h8n8g3koaxp/angles.txt/file)

Answer (score 0):

Solved: R trig functions use radians, so the script was converting to degrees needlessly and causing over-correction at a scale of 180/pi.